# Populate input field using selected row angular dynamic array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs, formarray

Why my second row gaves me same values from my first row when i selected value in my list?

all okay when the second row added it gaves me some same val its weird though. cause when i tried to input some value its okay.

> HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="Form">
  <div formArrayName="ItemRec">
    <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>FORM</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let ItemRec of ItemRec.controls; let i = index;"
          [formGroupName]="i">
        <td (click)="removeRow(i)" style="width:100px" align="center">
          <i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i></td>
        <td>
          <input style="width:200px" class="form-control"
                 formControlName="dr" ngModel={{transactionCode}}>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

> .TS

```
this.Form = this.fb.group({
    Id:['0'],
    ItemRec: this.fb.array([this.CreateItemRec()])
  })
}  


CreateItemRec(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    id:[0],
    dr: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
  })
}

get ItemRec(): FormArray {
  return <FormArray>this.Form.get('ItemRec') as 
  FormArray
}


addRow(): void {
  this.ItemRec?.push(this.CreateItemRec());
```

The list of my value is in the modal inside of that is mat table.

Answer (score 0):

> formControlName="dr" ngModel={{transactionCode}}

You are mixing **template driven forms** with **reactive forms**. That can have unexpected behavior. Kindly remove the ngModel.

I guess it is set as default value for every field created by ngFor. If it is supposed to be the default value, set it at form creation.

```
CreateItemRec(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    id:[0],
    dr: new FormControl(this.transactionCode, Validators.required),
  })
}
```

Comment: thank you for your time, but i tried this one and got the same value